# SQL Server sys.allocation_units - what is used_pages

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to clean up a data base i inherited. I found a query that brings up all the tables with `used_pages` from a table `sys.allocation_units`

I cant find online any info regarding what is `used_pages`

Comment: what do you mean with "clean up database"? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

From `sys.allocation_units` `used_pages` is the number of total pages actually in use.

[SOURCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189792.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

sys.allocation_units is Contains a row for each allocation unit in the database.

if you want to manage disk, you can re-design your Database.

if know you about Pages and Extents Architecture, use below guide :

[Guide link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/pages-and-extents-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver15)